# Registration form inline password generation?

Tags: forms, login, password

A client has given me "design direction" for their site's account creation form (it's a utility site) that includes an option to have the system generate a password for the user inline on the form, adjacent to the password field. My gut says that generating a random password will actually result in forgotten login troubles later - especially since it's a utility site the user will likely only log into once a month - but I can't find anything to back up (or debunk) my suspicion. Anyone seen anything, or have a well-informed opinion on whether/how inline password generation affects login success rates? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to the site, @Malisams! +1 for `or debunk`. (I think your suspicion's probably right, but I like this more neutral way of phrasing the question.)

Answer (score 2):

As your client is likely wanting to produce a password for the user to avoid them selecting a commonly weak password:

[image]

Why do people keep doing this!? Because they can *remember* them!

It might be helpful to point out to your client that [The Only Secure Password is the One You Can't Remember](http://www.troyhunt.com/2011/03/only-secure-password-is-one-you-cant.html).

The above article points out many tricks to creating passwords, such as Google's suggestions in this YouTube video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0RCsHJfHL_4

Which both the article and this [xkcd](http://xkcd.com/) strip quickly debunk as being at all useful:

[image]

In giving the user a meaningless random "strong" password, they will immediately defeat its purpose by writing it down; or changing it to something they will better remember.

Commonly cited principles of short-term memory include George Miller's [Magic Number 7](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Magical_Number_Seven,_Plus_or_Minus_Two), in which people can retain 7 +/- 2 items in short term memory at a time. Additional are multiple studies that have shown that memory lasts between 15-30 seconds, without rehearsal or some other memory aid.

Given an 8-digit random "strong" password, absent of personal context, the user may hold onto that memory long enough to hit the submit button -- unless they are asked to remember something else along the way. Beyond that it will quickly fade without employing a retention tactic, such as [rehearsal or repetition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-term_memory#Capacity_of_short-term_memory).

### Prove it to them...

You could easily demonstrate how difficult this will be to users. Give your clients a flashcard with the random "password" on it. Don't hide what you are doing and give them a chance to try and remember it; 2-5 minutes. Then continue your meeting with them. At the end of the meeting (let's assume a 30 minute meeting), ask them what their password is.

If you are remote to your client, you can do the same in an e-mail. Give them a random password in an e-mail and tell them to remember it. A week later, ask them what it is. If they're honest, they'll tell you they had to go look in their e-mail (probably).

Comment: "employ a retention tactic" like the browser's save password feature, which I think has pretty low usage rate. I would be very interested to see statistics on that.

Comment: if you are remote to your client and don't trust them to be humble, do it with during the next Skype / FaceTime type conference call